# Swift: constrain a generic parameter for use in a more constrained generic function

Tags: swift, function, generics

I'm implementing a class which needs to conform to a protocol that looks like this:

```
protocol P {
    func magic<T>(_ thing: Thing, as type: T.Type) -> T
}
```

This protocol is provided by third-party code, **which means I can't change it in any way** in order to solve this problem.

Now, I have a generic function

```
func magicForObject<T: AnyObject>(_ thing: Thing, as type: T.Type) -> T
```

and I want to call it from within my implementation of `magic`, just for input `thing`s which are in fact objects.
That is, I want to do something like this:

```
func magic<T>(_ thing: Thing, as type: T.Type) -> T {
    if T.self is AnyClass {
        return magicForObject(thing, as: type)
    }
    else {
        // do something else
    }
}
```

but I can't find any way to make this work. The code above obviously doesn't compile, and neither does stuff like

```
if let T_ = T.self as? AnyClass { ... }
```

because `T_` is just a normal variable, not a generic parameter (which is presumably compile-time).

I also tried doing this:

```
func magic<T: AnyObject>(_ thing: Thing, as type: T.Type) -> T { ... }
func magic<T>(_ thing: Thing, as type: T.Type) -> T { ... }
```

and implementing the two separately. The constrained `AnyObject` one is correctly called if calling this function directly on the object, but *not* when the object is cast to protocol type `P`, in which case the second one is always used.

This situation seems hopelessly constrained, but are there any workarounds I haven't thought of?

### Update

It looks like this isn't currently possible in Swift. I've made a [post pitching the idea](https://forums.swift.org/t/conditionally-further-constrain-a-generic-parameter/15425/) in the Swift forums; please feel free to chime in if this is something you also need.

Comment: So what you're trying to do is check if the generic parameter in `magic` is a `class` then you want to do something with that class and return it from `magicForObject` as opposed to `structs`. Did I understand this correctly? Also you are providing your own default implementation for the protocol correct?

Comment: @Serj yes, if `T` `magic` is a class type, I want to be able to get a `T_: AnyObject` of some sort so I can call `magicForObject`, and otherwise do something else for structs etc.

This isn't for a default implementation of `P`, I just have a class which needs to conform to `P`.

Answer (score 1):

Your example is kind of hard to work with, so I had to do a lot of assumptions, but I guess this should do it for what you are requiring.

From what you said you have a given protocol P:

```
protocol P {
    func magic<T>(_ thing: Thing, as type: T.Type) -> T
}
```

Lets give P a default implementation of what you need it to do:

```
extension P {
    // Implementation for magic where T is a class
    func magic<T>(_ thing: Thing, as type: T.Type) -> T where T: AnyObject {
        print("AnyObject Called")
        return Test2() as! T
    }

    // Implementation for magic where T is a struct
    func magic<T>(_ thing: Thing, as type: T.Type) -> T {
        print("Struct Called")
        return Test() as! T
    }
}
```

You have a class that will conform to P

```
class Test2: P {

}
```

Lets assume you have this Thing object and a struct we want to pass to see if we have the right results:

```
class Thing {

}

struct Test {

}
```

Now lets test if we call `magic` on `Test2` if it will call the right function accordingly to what `type` is passed to `magic`

```
let test = Test()
let test2 = Test2()

// T is Test2 so its a class
test2.magic(Thing(), as: Test2.self)
// T is Test so its a struct
test2.magic(Thing(), as: Test.self)
```

The Print Output calls

```
AnyObject Called
Struct Called
```

which seems like you could do something for `structs` and another thing for `classes`

Comment: I tried this and got the same result. But now, try writing `let test2 = Test2() as P` and you won't get this result anymore...

Comment: Question is P always going to behave the same in any class that implements it?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. The issue with this approach is that when you use `Test2` by its protocol type, the correct `magic` is no longer called.

Comment: What I mean is that you can extend `P` and implement `magic` as I did for `Test2` and things should work again, but that means any class or struct implementing `P` will have that default implementation, but for sure you can override that implementation.

Comment: That works, but unfortunately in my case I can't just add a default implementation for `P`, so I guess I'm still a bit stuck...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178532/discussion-between-serj-and-greg).